# How to enable Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb) in Microsoft Azure windows server 2012 R2?

Tags: php, azure, virtual-machine, ms-access-2007, windows-server-2012-r2

I have virtual machine(Windows server 2012 R2) in Azure server (Plan as A0).

I cant find ODBC Data source in Administrative Tools.

I want to use below ODBC connection for my application.

```
 new PDO("odbc:DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};charset=UTF-8; DBQ=$destination_file; Uid=$db_username; Pwd=$db_password;") or die("Invalid user credentials for Access file.");
```

Answer (score 0):

> I cant find ODBC Data source in Administrative Tools.

It seems strange, I have created an A0 VM on Azure to have a further check, I could get [ODBC Data Source] from Administrative tool:
[image]
Could you please try to search 'Administrative tool' again in Azure VM and double check if it works, or try to set up another VM to see if the issue can be reproduced.

Comment: Thanks for ur response Ming Xu. Need to enable any thing from Server Manager?

Comment: I have not made any changes in VM, only created it via Azure portal and RDP to the VM, then provided the screenshot here. Have you tried to create another VM to see if the issue could be reproduced?